# Row and container inside navbar is not working properly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In my project, I am using bootstrap 4. When I use container inside navbar and row inside container, row is not taking full width of container as it should do. Am I missing something or something that is strange here?

My code -

```
    <!-- Wrapper -->
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                        </form>
                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- End of wrapper -->
```

Expected Output - Row should take width of container.

Actual output - Row is not taking the width of container instead its taking width of 337px only while container is 1170px of width

Comment: can you replace `container` with `container-fluid` and check :)

Comment: I checked it @AkhilAravind but still same issue is there.

Comment: can you add your expected Output and current output

Comment: bootstrap has a style defined for container under navbar, something like .navbar>.container, .navbar>.container-fluid { display: flex; /* other properties also... */} , so getting full width of container you may need to write custom css in separate file that can override that behavior. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason to use the grid (`row`, `col`) inside the Navbar, and the grid is [not supported Navbar content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/navbar/#supported-content). 
Just use the `container`...

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/0ybzGU0ugF

The reason *"row is not taking the width of container instead its taking width of 337px only while container is 1170px of width"*, is because the `container` is display:flex inside the `navbar` and therefore `row` becomes a flexbox child causing it to shrink in width.